# AWS Glue request limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Have some lambdas that request schemas form AWS Glue. Would like to know if there is a limit of requests to AWS Glue after which Glue cannot handle it? Load testing in other words.
Have not found anything about it in official documentation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The various default, per-region limits for the AWS Glue service are listed at the below link. You can request increases to these limits via the support console.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/troubleshooting-service-limits.html

These limits are not a guaranteed capacity unless there is an SLA defined for the service, which I don't think Glue has. One would assume that EC2 is the backing service though so capacity should theoretically not be an issue. You will only know by running your workflow over a long period of time to see the true availability of the service if there is no SLA.

Comment: Very nice, that must be a new one. They added a bunch of new SLAs this year

Answer (score 0):

have a look here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/glue.html

as of today (2020/01/27):

```
Number of jobs per trigger  50
```